# Android Device Owner Mode by App Signed with platform key (or use signed App for custom device policy)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-device-owner

I have application signed by platform key and I need to move device to kiosk mode.

**What kiosk mode mean in my case:**

- Set user restrictions (change default activities, set VPN etc...)
- Prevent user access to third party apps, some system apps etc...
- Set custom Activity as Home activity without user interaction
- Move application to lock task mode

I know that DevicePolicyManager could do that. But device doesn't have any google's provisioning system (like NFC or QR). Is exist any way to set device owner using application signed by platform key or use such application with benefits of device owner App?

Answer (score 1):

I find out that application with system privileges could do al lot of thing that could be done with DevicePolicyManager. But some of functionality provided as hide API:

1. Set user restrictions - could be done with UserManager
2. Prevent user access to third party apps - could be done be disabling such apps with package manager
3. Set custom Activity as Home activity without user interaction - could be done with PackageManager
4. Move application to lock task mode - could be done by disabling UI components in status bar and system navigation bar with StatusBarService

Answer (score 0):

The platform key only gives you certain permissions to take a certain role or to make some system settings, but for your task you are mainly right with the DevicePolicyManager. I do not see why you need NFC or QR for that, you could implement a simple code to unlock the kiosk mode.

There are of course finished applications to do that and you would not need to re-invent the wheel as this kind of application is not trivial.

Comment: For my case it should be custom application. (c) "I do not see why you need NFC or QR for that, you could implement a simple code to unlock the kiosk mode."  - Because I found the only way to do that on device without google services, is set it via adb. But I need to  provide provisioning system available for  regular users. Could you please provide me that  (c) "simple code to unlock the kiosk mode"?

Comment: The advantage of NFC is that you can listen in the background and do not need a UI (Button, etc.) for that. QR would need anything to instantiate the scan anyway. I used to implement a combination of invisible buttons that need to be touched in a certain way to show up a dialog to enter a customizable unlock-code (numbers), but this is depending on your application